# numpy alternative to successive indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm sure this is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find another question with exactly what I wanted so apologies in advance.

Given the following example array:

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]]])
```

I want to find an equivalent of:

```
idx0, idx1 = [0,1], [0,2]
arr[idx0,...][:,idx1,:]
```

Which returns:

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [10, 11]]])
```

I'm sure there's a better/more concise way of doing this, but I can't find it.

Comment: The return value appears to have the same dimensionality as the original array, but only contains the 1st and 3rd rows from the 1st and 2nd block - how does that relate to your coordinates `[0,1], [0,2]`? It's not that hard to write a line of code that would select these values, but it's not clear that you just want to index them directly?

Comment: So the actual array is much larger and I’ll have two lists of indexes to select along the zeroth and first dimensions. 

I chose [0,1] (first and second block) and [0,2] (first and third row of each block) arbitrarily to illustrate the output I want to achieve.

Comment: I think the way you index is actually what you should do if the index tuple is not decribed by a slice object. If you just want to avoid the double brackets you could use `np.take` as in: `np.take(a[idx0], idx1, axis=1)`.

Comment: `arr[np.array(idx0)[:,None], idx1]`, IIUC or `arr[np.ix_(idx0, idx1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[[ 0,  1],
      [ 2,  3],
      [ 4,  5]],

     [[ 6,  7],
      [ 8,  9],
      [10, 11]],

     [[12, 13],
      [14, 15],
      [16, 17]]]
)

result = a[0:2, [0, 2]]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [10 11]]]
```

The `0:2` part of the indexing selects the first two elements at the top level, the `[0, 2]` part selects only the first and third row of the results at the next level.

In the comments you clarified and asked about the specific difference between these two approaches:

```
result1 = a[0:2, [0, 2]]
result2 = a[[0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

It's a good question, because at face value, `[0, 1]` comes down to the same result as `[0:2]` in this case, after all:

```
print(a[0:2] == a[[0, 1]])              # prints an all `True` array
print(a[0:2].shape == a[[0, 1]].shape)  # prints `True`
```

However, [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) states: "Note that in Python, x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former."

And that's the issue here.

Compare:

```
result1 = a[[0, 1]][:, [0, 2]]  # works as needed
result2 = a[0:2, [0, 2]]        # same
```

However,

```
result3 = a[[0, 1], [0, 2]]     # this
result5 = a[[(0, 1), (0, 2)]]   # is just the same as this
```

So, you're just selecting the `0, 0` and `1, 2` elements.

To use the syntax from your example, for a correct result:

```
idx0, idx1 = slice(0, 2), [0, 2]
result = a[idx0, idx1]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [10 11]]]
```

As user @hpaulj correctly pointed out, this may be what you were looking for:

```
idx0, idx1 = [[0], [1]], [0, 2]
result = a[idx0, idx1]
print(result)
```

Instead of a slice, using a nested list.

Comment: Another option for `[0, 2]`: `:3:2`

Comment: So when I tried arr[idx0, idx1] I got [[0,1],[10,11]] which is the reason for my question. Is there some difference in what I'm doing? For reference the real array is much larger which I why I'm trying to use index arrays like this.

Comment: @MechanicPig, that's assuming they actually want every 2nd row, starting at the first - that happens to be the same in this case, but it's not a given.

Comment: @DomByrne I updated the answer to clarify on that specifically.

Comment: @Grismar Ok thank you! I’m not at my pc right now to check but I would arr[idx0, (idx1)] achieve the same as arr[idx0,…][:,idx1,:] then? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, if both parts in the sequence are not slices, but just sequences themselves, they basically make up a set of coordinates into the array, instead of working the way you need them to - you want a slice for the first part.

Comment: a[[[0], [1]], [0, 2]]

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer with that suggestion.